# ACCESS Form -> Subform 3 Datasheet view reference error

Tags: forms, ms-access, subform

I had a main form and was able to reference subform 2 without issue and added another filter layer via another subform and now I cannot reference the final subform (and even subform2 is not referencing) :(

the original reference was:

Me.SFRM_InventoryCategories.Form.SFRM_MaterialFormPricing_ALL.Form.RecordSource

The revised reference should have been:

Me.SFRM_CategoryCategories.Form.SFRM_InventoryCategories.Form.SFRM_MaterialFormPricing_ALL.Form.RecordSource

But that didn't work so I added the appropriate !s:
Me!SFRM_CategoryCategories.Form!SFRM_InventoryCategories.Form!SFRM_MaterialFormPricing_ALL.Form.RecordSource

But that didnt work either!

originally, the first subform was a continuous form with a datasheet subform in he footer. adding the additional filter subform made all three of the subforms datasheets. Is there an issue with referencing a subform of a subform if it is set as datasheet view?

I would appreciate any help getting this reference to work!

Comment: So you have a form>subform>subform>subform arrangement?

Comment: First revised syntax works for me if a record in the last subform has focus. And still works if I set focus on higher level records related to the expanded last form record. I have never used datasheet/subdatasheet setup.